# I can't completely remove snapd because of the error snap core is not removeable it is used by the model

Tags: command-line, snap

I am trying to remove all the snap packages and installing the flathub one's, i am a beginner and i had changed my os to linux from windows 2 days ago, and while watching some of the tutorials all the youtubers told to use flathub packages and to do so i watched that you have to first remove snap packages and while doing it by watching a tutorial, i came to an error which is like this:
error: cannot remove "core": snap "core" is not removable: snap is used by the
model
If anyone know about this please help me.

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; so we're somewhat limited in what help we can provide. I've removed all *snap* infrastructure on a number of Ubuntu desktop/*flavor* releases due to howto posts I saw (*to see if they worked*) and saw no issues with them, but you've provided no clues as to what you did, what message(s) or error(s) you actually got (*including the command that caused it!*) except vague mention of it, thus we can't currently help.

Comment: "*[A]ll the youtubers told to use flathub packages*" Some folks prefer Flatpaks. Some prefer Snaps. Some prefer Debs. All work with Ubuntu. None require removal of others. Advice: Avoid the strong, exclusionary opinions of zealots.

Comment: Combining "I am a beginner ... 2 days ago" and doing major "youtube" inspired system surgery is a Bad Idea. Don't commit UTBLT! (Using Tool Before Learning Tool).. Disaster awaits.